# RTL layout Direction of menu items by using Kotlin

Tags: android, menu, kotlin, right-to-left

How to apply `layoutDirection` RTL because I have a Slide menu And I need to `align` the Direction items for (drawable image and text) to be right to left And when I Try adding these attributes

```
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
```

It's not working, Any help?

Note: in the Manifest file I'm using `android:supportsRtl="true"`

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private var myToolbar:Toolbar? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myToolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)
        title = ""

         val drawer = findViewById<View>(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
         val menuRight = findViewById<View>(R.id.menuRight) as ImageButton
        menuRight.setOnClickListener {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
            }
        }
        val navigationView2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view2) as NavigationView
        navigationView2.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        val id = item.itemId
         var text = ""
    if (id == R.id.nav_home)
            {
                text = "home"
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_bar) {
                text = "bar"
                val i = Intent(this, ViewDatabase::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_pool) {
                text = "pool"
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
                text = "exit"
                signOut()
            }
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen $text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val drawer = findViewById<View>(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
        return true
    }
```

**activity_main_drawer1.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="end"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="Home"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_white_24dp"
            android:title="Bar"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pool"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_pool_white_24dp"
            android:title="Pool"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_exit"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="exit"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="end"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    </menu>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.mbdb.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/xx"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/e"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menuRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/xx" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**nav_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Coding new"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your device configuration RTL?

Comment: @mTak do you mean the configuration RTL from setting and choice `developer option` and then `Force RTL layout`? but this  option does not exist  on my device (API  level 18)